# How to inserting a few column to Hive table?

Tags: apache, hive, bigdata

i have the table in apache hive,

```
create table example(
 name String,
 age int,
sex boolean
)coment'this is example table'
patitioned by(year int,month int,day int);
```

right now, i want to insert into only one column is name

```
insert into example(name)  patition(2016,12,10) values("peter");
```

but its not active ? i don't understand.
please could you tell me why ?

Comment: which data formate  used ?

Comment: i try with parquet it's working but not workiing well with CSV

Comment: yes, table i'm using is parquet table,

Comment: then you have to just mansion proper header